# Safe values to be used as key in shmget

Tags: c++, linux, key, shared-memory

I'm using shmget for sharing data between processes of my project on Linux.

```
int shmget(key_t key, size_t size, int shmflg);
```

However, any other programs can call to shmget too, and thus it may lead to key conflict (because I use a constant as the key to call shmget, I must use a constant instead of a generated key because the lateral processes are built and run separately).

What should be the safe values to be used as key in shmget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use the POSIX [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/shm_open.html) (with `mmap`) instead, It doesn't have the problem of collisions that exists with `ftok` so long as you aren't using the same named region as other software.

Answer (score 6):

There are no safe values, and you (and every other process creating shared segment) should use `IPC_EXCL` to ensure there is no collision. However, the latter should ensure that other programs don't start writing into your segment (unless they are written badly).

You can try building your 'private' key constant off [ftok()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftok) but well, you know it ain't safe. If you collide with something, you won't have a way to tell your programs that this is not the right key. Also remember that:

> Only the low-order 8-bits of `id` are significant.  The  behavior  of  ftok()  is unspecified if these bits are 0.

In other words, don't pass `0` there ;).

In any case, you should *seriously* consider creating some channel of communication. A single file written by the server with id would be enough, which would be then read by other programs.

From other ideas, you may try passing server PID as `id`, if other processes can get at least that. This could make it a bit 'safer'.

Comment: i'm thinking of generating random keys, and repeat creating shm segment with IPC_EXCL flag until an acceptable key is found, but i don't know if it is a good option

Comment: @PaulDinh: yes, that's a good option. Well, but you have to have a way to generate random keys, without relying on specific `sizeof(key_t)`; I'd just use random `id` for ftok() then.

Comment: In case you have a client-server scenario wherein each client maintains a shared-memory segment for efficient IPC with the server, one nice option for unique `shmget()` keys is to base them on the `gettid()` system call, which returns the thread ID of the caller. This is Linux-specific, though.